# DocuSign: How to add recipientSignatureProviderInfo to the payload text/csv of Bulkrecipients

Tags: csv, content-type, docusignapi, bulk

I can see that in the REST API documentation on [bulkrecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/BulkEnvelopes/EnvelopeBulkRecipients/update/), the object recipientSignatureProviderInfo can be added to the JSON payload :

```
{
    "bulkRecipients": [
        {
            "rowNumber": "sample string 1",
            "email": "sample string 2",
            "name": "sample string 3",
            "note": "sample string 4",
            "accessCode": "sample string 5",
            "identification": "sample string 6",
            "phoneNumber": "sample string 7",
            "tabLabels": [
                {
                    "name": "sample string 1",
                    "value": "sample string 2"
                }
            ],
            "recipientSignatureProviderInfo": [
                {
                    "name": "sample string 1",
                    "value": "sample string 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But what is the correct way to add this to a text/csv content-type ?

for example :

```
Name,Email,Note,AccessCode,Identification,PhoneNumber,address1
David Jones,david.jones@yahoo.com,Here is the document we discussed.,,ID Check,,123 Main St
Kevin Smith,kevinmith@yahoo.com,,2243,,,697 My Way
Elisabeth Bozick,elisabeth.bozick@yahoo.com,,,phone,usersupplied,827 1st Ave
```

Whta is the correct header name ?  I tried "recipientSignatureProviderInfo" but that didn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

The `recipientSignatureProviderInfo` column is not supported in the Bulk recipient CSV file.

Here is the link to [Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/DocuSignHelp/Content/create-recipient-list.htm#Supported_column_headers_)

Only the following columns are supported.

- Name
- Email
- Note
- AccessCode
- Identification
- PhoneNumber
- DocuSign Field Name

---

*Additional resources.*

https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-send-a-document-using-bulk-send